# adding the duplicate data to the array: error

Tags: swift

my problem is adding the duplicate data to the array

my program it works well before it can be refresh manually but duplicate added to list when manually refreshed

when I check the print, the data is added to the double list

print result

> ARRAYLAR : ["EXAMPLE", "EXAMPLE"]

Watch the video for a better understanding of the problem
[VİDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ocrIw3REN_Q)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    getData()
}



@objc func getData() {


        self.konuAdiArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        self.konuHedefTarihArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        self.konuTestArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        self.konuIDArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        self.veriGirisArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)




    Database.database().reference().child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("dersler").child(gelenDersID!).child("konular").observe(DataEventType.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let values = snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary


            self.konuAdiArray.append(values["konuAdi"]as! String)
            self.konuHedefTarihArray.append(values["konuHedefTarihi"]as! String)
            self.konuTestArray.append(values["konuTestHedefi"]as! String)
            self.veriGirisArray.append(values["veriGirisSoru"]as! String)
            self.konuIDArray.append(snapshot.key)

        print("ARRAYLAR : \(self.konuAdiArray)")

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

}
```

refreshBarButton code

```
@IBAction func refreshBarButton(_ sender: Any) {
    getData()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make separate function for observing changes of your data base. When you call `getData()` you code calls twice of DB changes. So that you subscribe on changes one more time that's why I'd recommend you to make separate function like `setDataBaseObserver()` which you call only one time in `viewDidLoad`. If you are updating your data you should make network request or take them from different source (not from data base again). Hope you understand me right!

```
func setDataBaseObserver() {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("dersler").child(gelenDersID!).child("konular").observe(DataEventType.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
       let values = snapshot.value! as! NSDictionary
         self.konuAdiArray.append(values["konuAdi"]as! String)
         self.konuHedefTarihArray.append(values["konuHedefTarihi"]as! String)
         self.konuTestArray.append(values["konuTestHedefi"]as! String)
         self.veriGirisArray.append(values["veriGirisSoru"]as! String)
         self.konuIDArray.append(snapshot.key)
         print("ARRAYLAR : \(self.konuAdiArray)")
         self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Hope it will help to you!

Comment: @ÖmerKaptan You are doing something wrong probably. If you can share your code - may be I can be useful

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for the manual refresh. You are observing `childAdded` on a Firebase database, which will continue to update in real time. Whenever you hit the manual refresh, your `getData()` is adding your controller as an observer *again*. Either remove the manual refresh control and just let Firebase do its thing (this is what it excels at - realtime updates without manual refresh), or change your `childAdded` observation to be a one-time data fetch.

Comment: how can ı do one-time data fetch

Comment: See the "Read Data Once" section in the Firebase docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write